# Change of variables for fourth-order PDE?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, change-of-variable

I have the following 4th-order linear PDE:

$$\dfrac{\partial^{4}\Psi}{\partial\rho^{4}}+2\phi\frac{\partial^{2}\Psi}{\partial\rho\,\partial\phi}+\frac{\partial^{2}\Psi}{\partial\phi^{2}}+\phi^{2}\frac{\partial^{2}\Psi}{\partial\rho^{2}}+\frac{\partial\Psi}{\partial\rho}=0$$

which I am aware can be factorised as

$$ \dfrac{\partial^{4}\Psi}{\partial\rho^{4}}+\left(\phi\frac{\partial}{\partial\rho}+\dfrac{\partial}{\partial\phi}\right)^{2}\Psi=0.$$

This PDE arises in a matched asymptotic expansions problem I am working through, where the outer problem involves a biharmonic operator. I was wondering whether there happens to be a change of variables which converts this equation into one that can be solved much more easily, e.g. using transform methods or similarity solutions?

Comment: I tried to apply a Fourier transform on your initial PDE and I got to a second order ODE with variable coefficients that has only derivatives with respect to the frequencies of variable $\phi$. Did you try something along these lines?